# Heroku / Django / MySQL : 2013 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query'

Tags: mysql, django, heroku

I've deployed a Django app to Heroku. The app works perfect in other environemnts, but in Heroku, one out of 5 request I got a Lost connection to MySQL server during query.
I'm not hitting the app a lot, just testing it and it's unusable. I'm not sure where to start debugging this.
I've added CONN_MAX_AGE = 60 to the django settings with the hope that keeping the connection alive would help, but no.

[image]

Comment: The most common reason for this error is you tried to insert or fetch a row larger than the `max_allowed_packet` configured on that MySQL instance. For example a long TEXT or BLOB field can cause this.

Comment: @BillKarwin this is happening even on simple SELECT queries. I'm not running INSERTS and also after refreshing, it works